# Using Python how to replace any number of substrings within a string, starting with dollar sign ($), with a string "abc"?

Tags: python, string, str-replace

How to replace any number of substrings within a string, starting with dollar sign `$`, with a string `abc`?

Input-
`"$xyz"`
Output
`abc`

Input-
`'$xyz'`
Output-
abc

Input-
`($xyz)`
Output
`(abc)`

Input-
`$xyz,`
Output-
`abc,`

Input-
`$xyz (ends with one of more of whitespaces)`
Output-
`abc (ends with same number of whitespaces)`

Comment: My input string includes the double quote, single quote, braces, comma and whitespace as a part of the string exactly the way i have mentioned above. Note that output is expected to remove double quote & single quote, but should not remove the braces, comma and whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the text in file /tmp/a1.txt

```
kljasd asdlasdj flasjd s;djf;sjd s;dj s;jd
lasdfl  as $kjhkjh klsjd  cslcj llakjcl $zz
$kjhu lsjd ls dcjsldj lscj $2 lj lj
```

run Linux command

```
sed -e 's/\$[^ $]*/ABC/g' /tmp/a1.txt
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> s1 = "kjhs $radsg cosid 32hr 34h8fh 340h 0 $s $e io "
>>> re.sub('\$[^ $]*','ABC', s1 )
'kjhs ABC cosid 32hr 34h8fh 340h 0 ABC ABC io '
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: And what if,  s1 = 'kjhs "$radsg" cosid 32hr ($mn) 34h8fh 340h 0 '$s' $e, $io  '
Output expected is
s1 = 'kjhs abc cosid 32hr (abc) 34h8fh 340h 0 abc abc, abc  '

Answer (score 0):

I could actually do it now

s1 = 'kjhs "$radsg" cosid 32hr ($mn) 34h8fh 340h 0 '$s' $e, $io '

re.sub(r'('?"?)($[^\s,)]+)', r'abc', s1)

However if this is the string, I wanted to replace all but not $a. $a will not have any preceding strings but can have preceding whitespaces---
s1= '$a = kjhs "$radsg" cosid 32hr ($mn) 34h8fh 340h 0 '$s' $e, $io '